# Что(,) именно по-Вашему(,) в Вашей жизни верно!

Tags: запятые

Запятые не нужны, так?

> Делайте же Вы то, что(,) именно по-Вашему(,) в Вашей жизни верно!

Comment: Тематика вопроса интересная, почему поставлен минус?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Делайте же Вы то, что, именно по-Вашему, в Вашей жизни верно!* — *по-Вашему* — вводное слово; *именно* — усиливающая частица, относится к вводному слову, не отделяется от него запятой.

*Делайте же Вы то, что именно, по-Вашему, в Вашей жизни верно!* — вводное слово *по-Вашему* обособляется; частица *именно* относится к слову *Вашей*, отделяется от *по-Вашему* запятой.

*Делайте же Вы то, что именно по-Вашему в Вашей жизни верно!* — *(именно) по-Вашему* — обстоятельство; *верно (как?) по-Вашему*.

Comment: Пример: "В чем Именно, по-вашему, ум князя проявляется?" //  Можно ли в приведенном предложении отнести "именно" к вводному слову? Это будет  логическое подчеркивание... Но тогда это член предложения?

Comment: Так частицы, усиливая вводное слово, или какой-то оборот, или придаточное, могут, их частью являясь, не отделяться от них запятой.

Comment: Именно по-вАшему. Вводное слово в предложении попадает в ударную позицию  и становится членом предложения? Или нет?

Comment: Тема сама по себе интересная, но ее надо рассматривать в общем плане и на литературных примерах. Можно ли вообще к этому вводному слову что-либо добавить так, чтобы оно оставалось вводным словом, но не переходило в наречие.  Ударная позиция говорит о том, что "именно ваша" становится СМЫСЛОВЫМ центром высказывания, Но тогда это не вводное слово.  Слово "именно" в любом случае определяет смысловой центр.